# Конвертация JSON to YAML

Tags: python, json, yaml

Мне нужно конвертировать json файл в yaml, но не включая в начало строки тире и заключить заголовок блока в квадратные скобки. Вот так

```
[Debian 11]
k8s-023.123.test.ru
k8s-024.123.test.ru
k8s-025.123.test.ru
```

Однако при просто конвертировании я получаю такой вывод.

```
Debian 11:
- k8s-023.123.test.ru
- k8s-024.123.test.ru
- k8s-025.123.test.ru
```

Comment: Покажите исходные данные и ваш код

Comment: То что в первом примере - это не yaml, это скорее toml (и то не факт, что корректый).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал библиотеку js-yaml:

- Установить библиотеку js-yaml с помощью npm: npm install js-yaml
- Подключить библиотеку в коде: const yaml = require('js-yaml');
- Преобразуй json файл в yaml формат таким образом:

  const json = { Debian: 11, servers: ['k8s-023.123.test.ru', 'k8s-024.123.test.ru', 'k8s-025.123.test.ru'] }
  const yamlString = yaml.safeDump(json, { lineWidth: -1 });
  console.log(yamlString);

Что должно отобразиться консоли:

Debian: 11
servers:

- k8s-023.123.test.ru
- k8s-024.123.test.ru
- k8s-025.123.test.ru

Чтобы получить заголовок блока в квадратных скобках и не включая в начало строки тире - опция noCompatMode: true.

```
const yamlString = yaml.safeDump(json, { lineWidth: -1, noCompatMode: true });
```

Есть ещё такой вариант:

```
yamlString = yamlString.replace(/^-/gm, '');
yamlString = yamlString.replace(/(\w+):/g, '[$1]');
console.log(yamlString)
```

Посмотри, что из этого сработает